# Microphone is listening but has not been told to

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, microphone, creative

I have a Xtreme Gamer sound card (Creative SB X-Fi) and `dxdiag` tells me the driver I have is `ctaud2k.sys` version: `6.00.0001.1368`. The problem I'm having which I may try to resolve with driver re-installation (or see what happens on a fresh reboot first) is that I can hear myself through my headset microphone - it's listening. But `Listen to this device` is not ticked in the microphone properties. Like most microphones, I do also have +20dB boost enabled in order for anyone to hear me and its at 100% level, but there's no reason it should be listening and giving me feedback as well. Curse Creative and their shoddy drivers, and it's true that this issue seemingly comes and goes, but I was wondering if anyone can draw any light on it, or knows the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the speaker properties and click on the `Sound Blaster` tab and then go to `Settings` you should be in the Creative `Audio Control Panel`. In here, `Game Mode` appeared to be giving me feedback to my headphones from my microphone whereas `Entertainment Mode` and `Audio Creation Mode` do not.